# Does Libgdx AssetManager construct a new object every time the get method is called?

Tags: java, libgdx

If I load a TextureAtlas with the LibGDX AssetManager, does it automatically construct a new TextureAtlas at load time and then return the address to that object every time I call the get method? Or does it actually construct a new TextureAtlas upon every get method call?

The behavior I'm trying to implement is the former. I extended the Sprite class so it contains file names for the atlas and texture region corresponding to the sprite. I want to be able to read in a JSON file containing these names, and then initialize the sprite based on the JSON file, but I don't want each sprite to construct a new TextureAtlas just so that it can read the texture region. Rather, I want each sprite to contain a reference to a single TextureAtlas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a JSON `Serializer` that, upon reading the name of the `TextureAtlas`, will retrieve that atlas via an `AssetManager`. That way you will save resources and will have each atlas only once. You have to make sure though, that the atlases have been loaded first.

The `AssetManager` is very similar to a `TextureAtlas`. `AssetManager.get(...)` is equivalent to `TextureAtlas.find(...)`. Both of them do not create any new object. They will return the same object every time you call get() or find().

Answer (score 0):

`AssetManager.load()` will add an asset (such as TextureAtlas) to the load queue.

`AssetManager.finishLoading()` will create/construct assets that are in the load queue.
`AssetManager.update()` will do the same as above if called in succession until it returns true.

`AssetManager.get()` will return the created/existing asset, it will not create a new one.